# Why my endpoint testing function doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, supertest

I get weird error whenever i'm testing my endpoint through jasmine and superset.

```
import app from '../index'
import supertest from 'supertest'

const request = supertest(app);

describe("suite for testing the image endpoint response", () => {
    //done for supertest to tell when our endpoint is done to disconnect from server
    it('Server is up',  async (done)=>{
        const response =  await request.get('api/image');
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        done();
    })
})
```

> **The Error:**
>
> 1. suite for testing the image endpoint response Server is up
>
> - An asynchronous before/it/after function took a done callback but also returned a promise. Either remove the done callback (recommended)
>   or change the function to not return a promise. thrown
> - Unhandled promise rejection: Error: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
> - Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>
> Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 5 secs.

I tried to remove "done()" which is wrong to be removed since it closes the connection after the test, but still same error.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72704003/edit) your question to include the actual error text (not an image of the error text)  [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing `done` in parameters and `done()` in the last line, will make it work.